# For spherical triangle $\triangle ABC$, show that $\pi<A+B+C<3 \pi$.

Tags: trigonometry, spheres, spherical-trigonometry

> For spherical triangle $\triangle ABC$, show that $\pi<A+B+C<3 \pi$.

I know that sum of the spherical triangle's sides are less than $2\pi$ but cannot get a start to above problem.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but on a sphere, the area of a triangle and the sum of its angles are related (the formula can be found on internet). This is why "locally " the Earth is flat, because the area of a triangle is so small, the sum of the angles is 180. When the triangle is bigger, so is its angle sum. I would start with the origin of that formula

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to prove that the above relationship.

Comment: if you know that, please help

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31035/proof-that-the-angle-sum-of-a-triangle-is-always-greater-than-180-degrees-in-ell

Comment: Look up dual triangles [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/spheretrig.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj007rw0s7mAhWZAp0JHWITC2oQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0NpPiV44U9enGuZ5WWRIUw).  Apologies for the long link, when material downloads instead of appearing online I can't get rid of the search information.